# How to sort listview according to a specific listview item

Tags: android, listview

I am basically making an application which displays various food stores which are near to user's location.

I have successfully integrated google map but I am not able to filter my list view items according to nearest user location.

For example I have a list view item

> place

and its values goes as

> place1 , place2, place3, place4 and so on

and I want that if the user location is near to 'Place 1' then user should be shown food items of Place 1 first then Place 2,3 and 4.

So I want to sort list view according to a specific list view item (PLACE) and compare it with the user location and display results which are near to user.

I have no idea to do this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to use `Comparator` for sorting the list. Give more information regarding the adapter and backing data set for better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider storing all your data in two dimensional ArrayList, so that one of your columns would be "place". Then sort it using the code below and then pass it to the adapter.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> yourData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
yourData = /* initialize your data */ ;

Collections.sort(yourData, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> row1, ArrayList<String> row2) {
        return row1.get(0).compareTo(row2.get(0));  // "at 0 index your place
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You may store longitude and lattitude values in column "Place" for each restaurant. Then when you get the user's current location, you may launch some method that will calculate the distance between the user and your restaurants. The method may look like this:

```
float [] distResult = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(latA, lonA, latB, lonB, distResult);
float dist = distResult[0];
```

Store these calculated values in a seperate column. After the all calculations are done, you may call that sort method which will sort items based on the column that contains the distance between user's current location and your restaurants.

For more information about calculating the distance refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Comment: I am not getting this two dimensional arraylist. Can i just compare the listview item (PLACE) with the user location and display various stores around him.

Comment: Its one of the options. Your question doesn't explain how the data is stored. For different cases, there will be different approaches to sort list. Why two dimensional? I assume you could do it like this: First column is Place and the rest of the coulmns are the foods. Or any other structure. Of course you can use the code in different way.

Comment: @himanshudaswani I'm not sure if it is possible to sort already created list view items. I guess it is not possible. It is easier to pass already sorted data to adapter, then your data will appear as needed in listview. That's why you need to sort it before

Comment: i have 5 columns in which i am storing the dish_name,price,category,store_name and PLACE and this is the list item according to which sorting needs to be done so is it possible through two dimensional array list that i could store PLACE in one and others in second list and continue sorting. Another question is the example code doesn't shows to how to compare list view item (PLACE) to user location.

Comment: From your words it seems that you are already using two dimensional array or list. I mean the data is in the table format. So just put the right index of Place column in the code above. Now, you will need to store the data for places in some constant format. One of them will be your example given in question. It is strings place1, place2. However, the keyword may be something else because it must define the user location some how

Comment: I know it is taking really hard time to figure this out but you are teaching me how to sort the my listview according to this (PLACE) but I want how to compare this (PLACE) with user's location and I am using list not two dimensional array. You have bought me so close to figure this out.

Comment: Are you using longitude and lattitude to represent locations?

Comment: Thanks man!! this is it and I got a better idea we do not have to calculate lat long every single store. Mark the lat long of the street name or area name so that the distance measured should be b/w user's location and the area name and the listview will be sorted according to PLACE!! @Marat thanks man...

Comment: Glad to hear you've found solution. Consider Upvoting my answer. I would appreciate that :)

Comment: my reputation isn't enough high to do so they are saying i must have a  reputation to cast a upvote.

Comment: Oh, I see. It ok. If you wish you may return to it later) Any way thanks for the trial :)

Comment: yeah sure i'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take items in your adapter and sort it. Maybe you would need to extend standard ArrayAdapter for it. And not forget to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after sort.